# Should I run the next race? Or stay out because of my calves?

Tags: running, injury, long-distance-running, racing

**What is the best method to get to full recovery here so I can race?**

Last Saturday, I ran a 5k race, your typical high school race. After proper cool down for 30 minutes, later that night I biked 30 miles with clips on my road bike. I went fairly easy (only about 13mph avg.) so I thought that this would be like a cooldown or recovery ride.

Sunday I didn't feel too bad.

On Monday, we did a weight workout in the morning with exercises like box jumps, deadlift, (and core). I noticed my calves were a bit clinchy, but nothing bad at all. Pretty typical. Later in the day, we ran a speed workout. I was able to do the speeds but on the recovery jogs, I could hardly get my legs to move, I could really feel the pain in the upper part of the calves. I figured I would just get through this one workout, then I could back it down after.

Next day, waking up my calves were so sore, I couldn't move my leg in any way that used my calf muscle. I went onto bike the next day instead of running.

Day after, I skipped a meet, and took the day off. Coaches advice was to ice them and take ibuprofen 4x12hours. So I iced 2xs the rest of the night

And now today, I biked again, didn't feel as bad, but the pain was still there.

I have tomorrow (Friday) to take easy also...

On Saturday I have one of the bigger races of the season, and I would like to run it, any advice to get me to and through this race?

Thanks!

Comment: Racing twice in a week, plus all the training in between, seems like a pretty beefy load. I'd do the race but be really aware of your calves. Warm up extra good, don't static stretch cold . If it goes from "sore" to "pain", you're going to be walking it in.

Answer (score 1):

Biking uses your calf muscles as much as running depending how your foot position. I would lay off the bike until you can safely run your meets.